# %ERRORLEVEL% fails while building solution through visual studio command prompt

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I'm trying to build a solution through visual studio command prompt. I'm using VS 2012. I've written a script and I use it through VS command prompt. The script content is:

```
set BUILD_STATUS=%ERRORLEVEL%

msbuild C:\MyProj.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:platform=x64 /verbosity:minimal

@if %BUILD_STATUS%==1 goto fail

:fail

exit /B 1
```

If the solution is already compiled and it is up-to-date, then the error is returned and execution is terminating. The execution moves to :fail block directly without executing further lines. This happens only when solution is up-to-date, but out-of-date solutions work fine.

I tried the negation as well:

```
@if not %BUILD_STATUS%==0 goto fail
```

Please help.

Comment: seems you are capturing ERRORLEVEL *before* building instead of after it, are you sure that is what you want? Also afaik no matter what BUILD_STATUS is, it will always reach the :fail since you use just `if` but no `else`? Anyway, why do you want to use a script like this instead of simply calling msbuild directly?

Comment: @Milind, fix up your batch file, the way it is written makes no sense. After that try reproduce your problem. For me, msbuild always returns `0` on success and `1` when there is a build error.

Answer (score 2):

ERRORLEVEL is not an environment variable as you're trying to capture it. Rewrite your batch as:

```
msbuild C:\MyProj.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:platform=x64 /verbosity:minimal

@if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto fail

rem If no error, success
goto success

:fail
exit /B 1

:success
exit /B 0
```